# How to use protractor to specify `devicePixelRatio` for e2e testing?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, retina

We're using protractor for angularjs application e2e tests. We have a feature which will check the `devicePixelRatio` of `window`, then generate different image url in order to provide high-quality image for retina screens.

But how to test it with protractor? I can't find any option can specify it with protractor APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to fake it by setting the value of `window.devicePixelRatio` using `executeScript` or `executeAsyncScript`.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-webdriver-webdriver-prototype-executescript

```
browser.executeScript('window.devicePixelRatio = 2');
```

Comment: it doesn't work in my project. I use the 'phantomjs' to run the tests, but it doesn't get the retina images when I run this code (in first line of the test)

Comment: I found it phantomjs's issue. Phantomjs just not support it.